# lstlisting: Configuring it to support Julia type code

Tags: listings, programming, mathematics

I was writing my report, which uses notations from `Julia`, specifically `Catlab.jl`. This contains a lot of category theory related symbols. I read the documentation for `lstlisting` and it does not support Julia. But can I have a workaround to support this language or the symbolic nature. Here is an example for more insights:

```
\begin{singlespacing}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,caption={Wiring Diagram: objects and Morphism},label=listing:program]
using Catlab

@present DirectedWiringDiagram(FreeSymmetricMonoidalCategory) begin
    (X, Y, Z, W)::Ob
    f::Hom(X, Y)
    g::Hom(Y, X)
    h::Hom(X⊗Y, Z)
    k::Hom(Z, W⊗X)
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{singlespacing}
```

This throws an error on the line containing `h::Hom(X⊗Y, Z)` and `k::Hom(Z, W⊗X)` for the symbol ⊗, which says

```
LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "97.
LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence (�\expandafter\lst@FillFixed@).
LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "8A.
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Try adding `\lstset{literate={⊗}{$\otimes$}{1}}`

Comment: Welcome, instead of using `language=Python` you could also define the `Julia` language with `\lstdefinelanguage`. Thus, you also have the possibility to declare the common colours which this language usually ascribe to special characters or strings. See the `listings` package doc p. 23 ff.